# ktlint as the formatter in detekt

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, detekt

I am using detekt with ktlint for formatting my code is like below.

**detekt.gradle**

```
ext{
    toolVersion = "1.0.0-RC16"
}
detekt {
    input = files(...)

    filters = ".*/resources/.*,.*/build/.*"
    baseline = file("${project.rootDir}/tools/detekt-baseline.xml")
    reports{
        html{
            enabled = true
        }
        xml{
            enabled = false
        }
    }
    config = files(file("$project.rootDir/tools/detekt.yml"))
}

dependencies {
    detektPlugins "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:$toolVersion"
}
```

**detekt-baseline.yml**

```
autoCorrect: true

build:
  maxIssues: 10
  weights:
  # complexity: 2
  # LongParameterList: 1
  # style: 1
  # comments: 1
```

Project level **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext{...}
    repositories {...}
    dependencies {...}
}

plugins{
    id "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt" version "1.0.0-RC16"
}

apply from: 'tools/detekt.gradle'
...


allprojects {
    repositories {...}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As you can see I have added detekt plugin for formatting in **detekt.gradle**. I have also enabled `autoCorrect` in **detekt-baseline.yml**. But code is not formatted when I ran `./gradlew detekt`
Generated html report shows no findings, but the metrics are shown.

When I ran `./gradlew detekt` after commenting out following line in **detekt.gradle**.

```
//    config = files(file("$project.rootDir/tools/detekt.yml"))
```

It does shows me findings, including formatting issues (ex: needless blank lines)

**How could I configure detekt to auto format the code according to the ktlint?**

---

This is an android project.

Comment: did you find how?

Answer (score 5):

Since detekt 1.1.0-RC15, you have to enable the autoCorrect in gradle:

```
detekt {
    autoCorrect = true
}
```

https://detekt.github.io/detekt/changelog-rc.html#rc15